# How many outcomes can this selection have?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Say I am setting up a timetable. One subject has multiple lecture groups, and all the lecture groups share a uniform amount of lectures.

To further elaborate on the example, the subject I'm plotting is calculus, and it has 3 lecture groups each containing 3 lectures. I have to have 3 lectures on my timetable, but I can select these from any lecture group in any order, e.g. first lecture picked from the 1st lecture group, second lecture picked from the 3rd lecture group and third lecture group picked from the second lecture group.

The only restriction is, if I already picked the first lecture from the first lecture group, I can not pick the first lecture from another group to be part of my selection.

My question is, how would I calculate the amount of possible outcomes for this selection?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill $3$ boxes. You have $9$ options to fill them with. If I understood you correctly that means you have $9$ options for the first box then $6$ options for the second and then $7$ for the last. Total Possibilities: $9\times 6 \times 7$

- Why 6 and 7?

  - Since you already picked one in the first box there are 8 left, but with your restriction of not having any other first course that means 2 less.
  - 7 because 2 were already picked. So, $9-2=7$

What I don't understand in your question is if each lecture group has its own place. In other terms, in Lecture Group $A$, does Lecture $1$ HAVE to be first, Lecture $2$ second,... If that is the case the possibilities will be different. I would appreciate it if you could clarify this aspect of the question.

If the above is the case then the total possibilities are $3\times 3 \times 3$ because Lecture Group A, B, C each have a first course, second course, and third course. So, your first box has 3 possibilities--from A or B or C. Similarly for the other boxes the same idea applies. Notice that if you wished to have a different order to the boxes (i.e. first doesn't necessarily have to be first but there must be only one #1 lecture) then you simply have to multiply the initial possibilities by $3!$

Therefore, the total permutations are $3\times 3 \times 3 \times 3!=162\  \text{ways}$ I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to call the lectures $A, B, \text{ and } C$.

First we pick the order of lectures we want to hear.  There are $3!$ ways to arrage $ABC$.  Then from each lecture series we can only pick one of $3$ lectures.  Hence we get $3!\cdot 3^3$.